# Cant get width of table view or table view header until after viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
func setTableHeader(){
        let headerWidth = Double(tableHeader.frame.width) 
//  also tried    let headerWidth = Double(tableView.frame.width)
        print("header width is \(headerWidth)")
}

func viewWillAppear(){ output --> 351
  setTableHeader()
//also tried in View Did Appear
}

func viewDidDisappear(){ output --> 296
  setTableHeader()
}
```

The outputs refer to what occurs when run on Iphone SE.  I designed my tableview and table header with constraints in Storyboard with the Iphone 6 display.  I was able to get the result I wanted by changing setTableHeader to reflect view.frame.width - (left and right constraints from storyboard), however I was wondering why I couldnt get this to work, and what the less hacky work around would be?  Also I am in actuality setting the dimensions of table header's subviews inside setTableHeader, but these subviews have no constraints (programatically nor in storyboard), in case that is relevant.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , The solution was to override UIViewController().viewDidLayoutSubviews(), get the proper size of the header view based on it’s constraints, set the frame on the header, and reset it as the table header view

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

// Dynamic sizing for the header view
if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {
    let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    var headerFrame = headerView.frame

    // If we don't have this check, viewDidLayoutSubviews() will get
    // repeatedly, causing the app to hang.
    if height != headerFrame.size.height {
        headerFrame.size.height = height
        headerView.frame = headerFrame
        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add this code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method. 
All views got their actual sizes only alter layout. Method `viewDidLayoutSubviews` called before `viewDidAppear` and after `viewWillAppear`.